# how to convert a string into an array of variables

Tags: python, arrays

how can i take a string like this

```
string = "image1 [{'box': [35, 0, 112, 36], 'score': 0.8626706004142761, 'label': 'FACE_F'}, {'box': [71, 80, 149, 149], 'score': 0.8010843992233276, 'label': 'FACE_F'}, {'box': [0, 81, 80, 149], 'score': 0.7892318964004517, 'label': 'FACE_F'}]"
```

and turn it into variables like this?

```
filename = "image1"
box = [35, 0, 112, 36]
score = 0.8010843992233276
label = "FACE_F"
```

or if there are more than one of box, score, or label

```
filename = "image1"
box = [[71, 80, 149, 149],  [35, 0, 112, 36], [0, 81, 80, 149]]
score = [0.8010843992233276, 0.8626706004142761, 0.7892318964004517]
label = ["FACE_F", "FACE_F", "FACE_F"]
```

this is how far i've gotten

```
log = open(r'C:\Users\15868\Desktop\python\log.txt', "r")
data = log.readline()
log.close()

print(data)

filename = data.split(" ")[0]
info = data.rsplit(" ")[1]

print(filename)
print(info)
```

output

```
[{'box':
image1
```

Comment: Creating variables dynamically is usually a bad idea. Instead of such dynamically generated variables you can create a dictionary with keys like `'box'` and `'score'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import ast
string = "image1 [{'box': [35, 0, 112, 36], 'score': 0.8626706004142761, 'label': 'FACE_F'}, {'box': [71, 80, 149, 149], 'score': 0.8010843992233276, 'label': 'FACE_F'}, {'box': [0, 81, 80, 149], 'score': 0.7892318964004517, 'label': 'FACE_F'}]"
filename, data = string.split(' ', 1)
data = ast.literal_eval(data)
print(filename)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
image1
[{'box': [35, 0, 112, 36], 'score': 0.8626706004142761, 'label': 'FACE_F'}, {'box': [71, 80, 149, 149], 'score': 0.8010843992233276, 'label': 'FACE_F'}, {'box': [0, 81, 80, 149], 'score': 0.7892318964004517, 'label': 'FACE_F'}]
```

(updated to follow your example of combining the keys):
From there I'd just write some simple code, something like:

```
box = []
score = []
label = []
for row in data:
    box.append(row['box'])
    score.append(row['score'])
    label.append(row['label'])
```

To unpack that data there are fancier ways but that is the most straight forward, for example:

```
box, score, label = zip(*{ x.values() for x in data })
```

Comment: It looks like this person wants each of the keys to also be variables. One way to go about that is to use the `globals()` dictionary and insert the key string to be equal to the value. e.g. globals()['box'] = [35, 0, 112, 36].

Comment: I appreciate that you both a) answer the question literally and b) show what is probably the more sensible way to do it.